# algorithm to map values to unit scale with logarithmic spacing

Tags: algorithm, math, transform

I'm looking for an algorithm to map values to a unit scale with logarithmic spacing. The scale ranges from 0 to 1.  Incoming values would be in the range of 0 to 10000.

0 maps to 0,  1 maps to .2,  10 maps to .4,  100 maps to .6
1000 maps to .8,  10000 maps to 1.0

Help/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: That's not logarithmic. 0.1 should map to 0 given the values of the function at 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000.

Answer (score 4):

If you are literally looking "to map values to a unit scale with logarithmic spacing", and with f(0)=0, then your example values are wrong.

However, you can do this with `f(x) = log(1+x)/log(1+max)`

So with `max=10000`, we have :

```
f(0)=0
f(1)=0.0753
f(2)=0.1193
f(10)=0.2603
f(100)=0.5010
f(1000)=0.7501
f(10000)=1
```

which on a log scale makes sense : if 1 is near 0 and 10000 is 1, then 100 which has the average number of zeroes of the previous numbers, should be around 0.5. You really don't wart to start considering `log(0)`as an option.

However, as soon as your minimum value is not `0` anymore (even if the `min` value is very very very small, as soon as it's non-zero), you can do a more reasonable interpolation :

```
f(x) = (log(x) - log(min)) / (log(max) - log(min))
```

which is [the same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithmic_identities) as user3246191's comment under his answer :

```
f(x) = log(x/min) / log(max/min)
```

Since all values returned by `f` in this post are fractions of logarithms, you can take the logarithm in any base you please. I would recommend the native one for your programming language (ie if `log10(x)` is defined as `ln(x)/ln(10)`, take `ln(x)` instead).

Answer (score 2):

It is not really clear what is the transform you are trying to apply. For what you try to say it seems that a potential function would be

f(x) = 0.2(1+ log(x)/log(10))

which satisfies f(1) = 0.2, f(10) = 0.4, f(100) = 0.6, f(1000) = 0.8, f(10000) = 1

but on the other hand f(0.1) = 0 and f(0) = -infty.

Of course it is possible to modify f so that f(0) = 0 but this will be somewhat arbitrary and your question is not really well formulated then.

Comment: Can you recommend a method for doing a similar transformation given an arbitrary input min and max range?  E.g. min=1. max=10e6.

Comment: f(x) = value_min + log(x / min) / log(max/min) * (value_max-value_min)

where x is between min and max and f(min) = value_min, f(max) = value_max